# Trocar a classe de um botão com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como eu faria para quando o usuário clicar um botão, abrir uma div e alterar a cor do botão? Como estou usando o Bootstrap, tentei dessa forma, mas só consegui abrir a div, mas não alterar a cor do botão:

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  function mostrarDiv(valor)
  {
    var valor;
    if(valor == 0)
    {
      document.getElementById('outros').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('categorias').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('btnOutros').className = 'btn btn-xlg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light';
    }
    if(valor == 1)
    {
      document.getElementById('outros').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('categorias').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('btnCategorias').className = 'btn btn-xlg  btn-primary waves-effect waves-light';
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Bootstrap**

```
<button type="button" id="btnOutros" class="btn btn-xlg  btn-inverse-primary waves-effect waves-light" onclick="mostrarDiv(0)"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Outros</button>
<button type="button" id="btnCategorias" class="btn btn-xlg btn-primary btn-inverse-primary waves-effect waves-light" onclick="mostrarDiv(1)"><i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i> Categorias</button>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="outros">
   Conteúdo
</div>
<div id="categorias">
   Conteúdo
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, removendo/adicionando apenas a classe em questão, sem ter que repetir todas as classes:

> Como disse o amigo, a variável `valor` já é passada na função, logo
>   não precisa declarar ela. Ao fazer `var valor;` na função, você está
>   sobrescrevendo o valor de `valor` que vem no parâmetro da função,
>   tornando-a *undefined*.

```js
function mostrarDiv(valor){
   if(!valor){ // significa que valor = 0
      document.getElementById('outros').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('categorias').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('btnCategorias').classList.remove("btn-primary");
      document.getElementById('btnOutros').classList.remove("btn-inverse-primary");
      document.getElementById('btnOutros').classList.add("btn-primary");
   }else{ // ou não é 0
      document.getElementById('outros').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('categorias').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('btnOutros').classList.remove("btn-primary");
      document.getElementById('btnCategorias').classList.remove("btn-inverse-primary");
      document.getElementById('btnCategorias').classList.add("btn-primary");
   }
}
```

```css
#outros{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="outros">outros</div>
<div id="categorias">categorias</div>
<button type="button" id="btnOutros" class="btn btn-xlg btn-inverse-primary waves-effect waves-light" onclick="mostrarDiv(0)"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Outros</button>
<button type="button" id="btnCategorias" class="btn btn-xlg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" onclick="mostrarDiv(1)"><i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i> Categorias</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado Sam.

Comment: Muito bem apresentado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro vc tem um erro porque está a declarar a variável valor e ela já é passada como argumento da function, não entendo o que queria nesse caso.

Segundo, eu executei o seu código e o botão muda de classe quando clico nele, está correto. Se você queria que existisse sempre mudança de um estado para outro já é outra coisa.

A minha única hipótese é que se esqueceu de referenciar os estilos no seu ficheiro.

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Obrigado Mauro.